# Not able to get results when running HTTPS GET requests on an array of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, get

I am using the code given below to run multiple https GET request for Wikipedia API.

```js
app.get("/data_results", (req, res) => {

    const articlesData = names.map(nameObj => {
        let name = nameObj.name;
        let articleExtract = "";
        let contentURL =
            `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
 action=query&titles=${name}&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=1&explaintext=false&origin=*`;

        // Getting article content
        https.get(contentURL, response => {
            response.on("data", async data => {
                const wikiArticle = JSON.parse(data);
                // Mapping the keys of the JSON data of query to its values.
                articleExtract = await Object.keys(wikiArticle.query.pages).map(key => wikiArticle.query.pages[key])[0].extract;
                nameObj.article = articleExtract.substring(0,350);
            })
        });

        return nameObj;
    });

    res.send(articlesData);});
```

This is my **names array**

```js
[
  { name: 'Indus%20Valley%20Civilisation' },
  { name: 'Ramayana' },
  { name: 'Mahabharata' },
  { name: 'Gautama%20Buddha' }
]
```

My aim :-

1. Run the HTTPS GET request for every value in the names array **sequentially**.
2. Add the article extract with its name and save in it in an objects array.

You could also suggest me better ways of doing this.

Comment: Your code doesn't wait for any of the asynchronous, non-blocking http requests to finish.  It calls `res.send(articlesData)` before any of the requests are done.  There are literally several thousand posts/answers here on this general subject.

Comment: How do I make it wait? I searched the net, but was not able to find any answers.

Comment: I added an answer that illustrates a couple ways to fix numerous problems in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. it creates an object  like

```
{
Mahabharata: response   
}
```

The code

```
const getValues = async () => {
  const name_array = [
    {name: 'Indus%20Valley%20Civilisation'},
    {name: 'Ramayana'},
    {name: 'Mahabharata'},
    {name: 'Gautama%20Buddha'},
  ];
  const namePromises = name_array.map(value =>
    fetch('baseurl' + value.name).then(res => res.json()),
  );
  const response = await Promise.all(namePromises);
  return response.reduce((obj, responseResults, index) => {
    obj[name_array[index].name] = responseResults;
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: yeah, this would work. But I also have another fetch api to fetch the images. How to I get both of them to result a singe object.

Comment: Follow the smaelogic

Comment: Follow the smaelogic

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. Could you guide me to resources where I can learn more about the concepts you used above?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `fetch` and `promise. all`. Map over your array of names and create promises as input. and then return the array of resolved promises.

something like this

```
const namePromises = [
      { name: 'Indus%20Valley%20Civilisation' },
      { name: 'Ramayana' },
      { name: 'Mahabharata' },
      { name: 'Gautama%20Buddha' }
    ].map((value) => fetch(baseurl + value.name).then(res=>res.json()));

    Promise.all(namePromises).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: i do not want to console log the extracted data. I want to store them all in a single objects array with the keys name : article name from the array and extract: article extracted from the api;

Comment: You can modify the function to get this result. let me edit the answer. Has this worked for you though

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

So, you have several things going on here.

1. `http.get()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  That means that the rest of your code continues to run while your multiple `http.get()` operations are running.  That means you end up calling `res.send(articlesData);` before any of the http requests are complete.
2. `.map()` is not promise-aware or asynchronous-aware so it will not wait its loop for any asynchronous operation.  As such, you're actually running ALL your http requests in parallel (they are all in-flight at the same time).  The `.map()` loop starts them all and then they all finish some time later.
3. The `data` event for `http.get()` is not guaranteed to contain all your data or even a whole piece of data.  It may just be a partial chunk of data.  So, while your code may seem to get a complete response now, different network or server conditions could change all that and reading the result of your http requests may stop functioning correctly.
4. You don't show where `names` comes from in your request handler.  If it's a statically declared array of objects declared in a higher-scoped variable, then this code has a problem that you're trying to modify the objects in that array in a request handler and multiple requests to this request handler can be conflicting with one another.
5. You don't show any error handling for errors in your http requests.
6. You're using `await` in a place it doesn't belong.  `await` only does something useful when you are awaiting a promise.

**Solutions:**

Managing asynchronous operations in Javascript, particularly when you have more than one to coordinate) is a whole lot easier when using promises instead of the plain callback that `http.get()` uses.  And, it's a whole lot easier to use promises when you use an http request interface that already supports promises.  My goto library for built-in promise support for http requests in nodejs is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).  There are many good choices shown [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

You can use `got()` and promises to control the asynchronous flow and error handling like this:

```
const got = require('got');

app.get("/data_results", (req, res) => {

    Promise.all(names.map(nameObj => {
        let name = nameObj.name;
        // create separate result object
        let result = { name };
        let contentURL =
            `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
 action=query&titles=${name}&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=1&explaintext=false&origin=*`;

        return got(contentURL).json().then(wikiArticle => {
            // Mapping the keys of the JSON data of query to its values.
            let articleExtract = Object.keys(wikiArticle.query.pages).map(key => wikiArticle.query.pages[key])[0].extract;
            result.article = articleExtract.substring(0, 350);
            return result;
        });
    })).then(articlesData => {
        res.send(articlesData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

This code attempts to fix all six of the above mentioned problems while still running all your http requests in parallel.

---

If your `names` array was large, running all these requests in parallel may consume too many resources, either locally or on the target server.  Or, it may run into rate limiting on the target server.  If that was an issue, you can run sequence the http requests to run them one at a time like this:

```
const got = require('got');

app.get("/data_results", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        let results = [];
        for (let nameObj of names) {
            let name = nameObj.name;
            let result = { name };
            let contentURL =
                `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
     action=query&titles=${name}&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=1&explaintext=false&origin=*`;

            const wikiArticle = await got(contentURL).json();
            let articleExtract = Object.keys(wikiArticle.query.pages).map(key => wikiArticle.query.pages[key])[0].extract;
            result.article = articleExtract.substring(0, 350);
            results.push(result);
        }
        res.send(results);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

---

If you really want to stick with `https.get()`, then you can "promisify" it and use it in place of `got()`:

```
function myGet(url, options = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let rawData = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    resolve(parsedData);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        }).on('error', reject);
    });
}

app.get("/data_results", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        let results = [];
        for (let nameObj of names) {
            let name = nameObj.name;
            let result = { name };
            let contentURL =
                `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
     action=query&titles=${name}&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=1&explaintext=false&origin=*`;

            const wikiArticle = await myGet(contentURL);
            let articleExtract = Object.keys(wikiArticle.query.pages).map(key => wikiArticle.query.pages[key])[0].extract;
            result.article = articleExtract.substring(0, 350);
            results.push(result);
        }
        res.send(results);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your response. Could you guide me to resources where I can learn more about the concepts you used above?

Comment: @spirit - I don't have specific resources to recommend.  I'd suggest searching for "asynchronous programming in nodejs" or "learning promises in nodejs".